# Вопрос по созданию мобильного меню для сайта

Tags: html, css

Возник вопрос по выпадающему меню.
Я пытаюсь сделать похожий сайт на Deezer.
Правильно ли я понял что у него по сути 2 меню - одно для высоких разрешений, другое для низких? (когда работает одно - скрыто другое и наоборот, с помощью display: none)
Получается мобильное меню появляется при низком разрешении с помощью медиа запроса и z-index делается видимым? И ставится width и height на 100% чтобы закрыть все остальные элементы от пользователя.

Является ли правильным такой подход? Или нужно с помощью скриптов менять уже имеющееся 1 меню и его стили?
пс - я знаю что в каком-нибудь бутстрапе это из коробки можно сделать за 5 минут и сразу все будет работать, но хочется научиться сначала делать все руками (сначала он мне показался гениальной штукой, а потом я сгорел от того что имеющиеся стили просто так не поменяешь)

Comment: Советую посмотреть в сторону медиазапросов (`css`) и не мучать `js`. Так же вы можете посмотреть как это уже реализованно в библиотеках (например `bootstrap`) и сделать похожее...так сказать "подглядеть"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Писать долго, держи обучающий видос: [правильное адаптивное меню бургер на HTML CSS и jQuery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chJQofBSx94)

Не дай погаснуть своему желанию изучить принципы работы каждого действия, с которым сталкиваешься в программировании. Это самое ценное в начале особенно, это - путь развития.

По теме вёрстки под разные разрешения - гугли CSS media queries

Comment: спасибо большое) про медиа запросы в курсе, просто думал что если "переделывать" с помощью медиа запросов единственное меню, то получится много лишнего кода css и выйдет не очень читаемо и "не красиво"

Comment: @Evgen161 никогда не бывает лишним использование технологий по их назначению. P.S.: Если помог, можешь нажать плюс и выбрать ответ